# OrderBy, ThenBy and IOrderedEnumerable<T>

Tags: linq

```
    string[] fruits = { "grape", "passionfruit", "banana", "mango", 
                          "orange", "raspberry", "apple", "blueberry" };

    // Sort the strings first by their length and then 
    //alphabetically by passing the identity selector function.
    IEnumerable<string> query =
        fruits.OrderBy(fruit => fruit.Length).ThenBy(fruit => fruit);
```

If we need more ordering than it is possible with a single call to `OrderBy`, then we should subsequently call `ThenBy` instead of OrderBy, since the sort performed by `ThenBy` is stable and thus preserves the ordering of input elements with equal key values.

a) In the above example `OrderBy` returns `IOrderedEnumerable<>` sequence **R** and in turn `ThenBy` is called on this sequence. When `OrderBy` returns **R**,  does **R** also store the key values (`fruit.Length` values ) which  were used by `OrderBy` to sort the elements in **R**?

b) Where in **R** are key values stored?

Thank you

Comment: Are you maybe thinking of `GroupBy`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer to this question lies somewhere different than you are thinking;

`OrderBy` and `ThenBy` are what are known as "deferred operators". What you described as the behavior is correct on some level, but actually not...

`OrderBy` does return a reference of the type you suggest. But that object is not a collection in the traditional sense; It is a part of an expression tree. Subsequent calls to `ThenBy` further modify this expression tree.

Said expression tree might actually do the sorting in the *reverse* order to what you might assume. It might even detect that you tried to do the same sorting each time, and not do them both (you haven't done any such thing in your example code, but I'm just making a point).

In particular, doing a single `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` could actually be quickly and easily done by doing those sorts... in reverse. Keeping in mind what is said about `OrderBy` being non-determinate...

```
var names = //initialize list of names;
var namesByAlpha = BubbleSort(names=>names);
var namesByAlphaAndLength = BubbleSort(namesByAlpha=>namesByAlpha.Length);
```

Assuming `BubbleSort` is a method which sorts by going down the list comparing each item to the next, and exchanging places when required (leaving equal cases alone), and repeats until the whole list no longer needs exchanging... this would end up with the same results as the LINQ methods you post... but note that it does the sort by names alpha *first*. When it sorts by length later, it would leave names of equivalent length in their alphabetical order, thereby appearing to `OrderBy` the length "first", then alphabetically.

`OrderBy` and `ThenBy` probably don't do a Bubble Sort (it's very inefficient on collections of any appreciable size at all), but to understand what they do, you need to understand they are building an expression tree that is executed when you enumerate the collection, and that expression tree is taking the total list of operations into account. It is not merely doing one sort, then doing the next... each as separate operations.

Comment: I don't know anything about expression trees, but I do understand what deferred operators are. For example,, OrderBy returns an object implementing IOrderedEnumerable<T>  and it is only when this object is being enumerated, will the OrderBy query actually be performed.
Anyways, the way I understand your explanation is that when ThenBy is called on object R returned by OrderBy, ThenBy doesn't actually enumerate object R, but instead just »modifies« R's code and returns this "modified" R to the caller?

Comment: Sort of; All deferred operators are not run in isolation at all, at any time. You can think of them that way to make it simpler to compose queries, but what is really happening is an expression tree involving *all* of the deferred operators is being built up; it is only finalized and executed when enumerated by some non-deferred operator or traditional enumeration sequence. So, `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` are *part of the same expression tree*.

Answer (score 2):

There are no "keys." `OrderBy` returns an enumerable of the same type as the original enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Your key values are generated from the elements in the list.  Since you still have access to the elements in the sorted list, you can still get the key value:

```
// enumerate the sorted list
foreach (string fruit in query) {
    int length = fruit.Length;  // grab the key value
    // do something with key value
}
```

Is that what you mean??  Maybe you are thinking about `GroupBy`, which would collect items with the same key value together?

Comment: "Is that what you mean??" No. Please see my reply to Andrew

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted to know how it actually *works*.  Sorry, I guess I'm too practical :)